# Using strncmp by checking only a variable single element of a char array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code which compares the letters of a char array one by one against a determined letter (letter 'l'). When this is the case in the output string, there are two 'l's.  For instance, "lily" should become "llilly". I fail to see how to implement this in C because something like this :

```
strncmp (word[indx],'l',1)  //where indx is an iterator of the char array 'word'
```

is not valid because the first argument should be 'word' but then there is no way to iterate through 'word'.

And of course if we wrote:

```
strncmp (word,'l',indx)
```

The problem is that now we are checking more than one letter at a time after `indx` becomes equal or larger than 2 and what we really want is to check one character at a time.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* ModifyString (char word []);

int main(){
  char word[6]="Hello";
  printf("The result is %s \n", ModifyString(word));
  return 0;
}

const char* ModifyString (char word []) {
  size_t lengthString=strlen(word);
  char modifiedString[lengthString*2+1]; //to fit the nul terminator and all the 'l's in case the word only contained 'l's.
  int indxModWord=0;

  for (int indx=0; indx<lengthString;indx++) {
    //This line does not express what I want to do:
    if (strncmp(word,"l",indx)==0) {
      modifiedString[indxModWord]=word[indx];
      indxModWord++;
    }

    // if 'l' in word make it appear twice in the output string
    else {
      modifiedString[indxModWord]='l';
      indxModWord++;
      modifiedString[indxModWord]='l';
      indxModWord++;
    }
  }

  printf("%s", modifiedString);
}
```

Does anyone has any idea how I should do this in C?

Comment: For a single character, you can use plain comparison. As in `word[indx] == 'l'`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Ok, I see. Thanks!

Comment: To check for a character in a string, research `strchr()`.

Comment: @Oriol  `const char *ModifyString()` does not return anything.   What should `ModifyString()` return?  Do you want `ModifyString(word)` to change `word` or somehow return a value without changing `word`?  This also implies you are compiling without all warnings enabled.   Save time, enable them all.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica. Thanks for your question.  Yes indeed there is a missing return value.  What I wanted to do initially was to return ' modifiedString'. But I  am not sure why 'return modifiedString" did not work (there is a problem related to such variable being local and I could not find a solution for that)  and I just printed it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply compare the characters as in other answers.

But of course, you can use `strncmp` to compare the chars if you wish.

```
strncmp (&word[indx],(char []){'l'},1);
```

or you can write the function:

```
int compareCharsUsingStrncmp(const char a, const char b)
{
    return strncmp((char[]){a}, (char[]){b}, 1);
}
```

or

```
int compareCharsUsingStrncmp(const char a, const char b)
{
    return strncmp(&a, &b, 1);
}
```

Smart compilers will not even call the `strncmp` :)

```
compareCharsUsingStrncmp:
        movzx   eax, dil
        movzx   esi, sil
        sub     eax, esi
        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

While traversing the given string, keep a check to see if the current character of the string is you target character (in your case 'l').

Code:

```
const char* ModifyString (char word [])
{
    size_t lengthString=strlen(word);
    char modifiedString[lengthString*2+1]; //to fit the nul terminator and all the 'l's in case the word only contained 'l's.

    int indxModWord=0;
    char targetCharacter = 'l';

    for (int indx=0; indx<lengthString; indx++)
    {
        if (word[indx] != targetCharacter)
        {

            modifiedString[indxModWord] = word[indx];
            indxModWord++;
        }
        else
        {
            modifiedString[indxModWord] = targetCharacter;
            indxModWord++;
            modifiedString[indxModWord] = targetCharacter;
            indxModWord++;

        }
    }
    modifiedString[indxModWord] = '\0';
    printf("%s", modifiedString);
}
```

Comment: Minor: better as `int indx=0 ...` --> `size_t indx=0 ...`.  Same for `indxModWord`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *ModifyString (char* word) {
   size_t  lengthString = strlen(word);

  //to fit the nul terminator and all the 'l's in case the word only contained 'l's.
  char *modifiedString;
  modifiedString=(char*)malloc(lengthString*2+1);

  size_t indxModWord=0;

  for (int indx=0; indx<lengthString;indx++) {

    //This line does not express what I want to do:
    if (word[indx] != 'l'){
      modifiedString[indxModWord]=word[indx];
      indxModWord++;
    }

    // if 'l' in word make it appear twice in the output string
    else {
      modifiedString[indxModWord]='l';
      indxModWord++;
      modifiedString[indxModWord]='l';
      indxModWord++;
    }
  }

  return (char *)modifiedString;
  
}

int main(){
  char word[]="Hello";
  char *result ;
  result =  ModifyString(word);
 
  printf("The result is %s \n",result);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Please check if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: `return modifiedString;` would return the address of a local array that becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: No need for the redundant cast on the return value, just use `return modifiedString;`